# how to compounding more that one matrixs into other matrix?

Tags: matrix

How to let more than one matrix to compose as one matrix

For example
`c = {{a, b}, {a, b}};
a = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
b = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}};`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`ArrayFlatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html):

```
c = ArrayFlatten[{{a, b}, {a, b}}]
```

> {{1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1}}

```
TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ c
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: I had no idea `TeXForm` was a thing. That's going to be so handy!